# Projection of a point on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a homework problem which I cannot solve.

Equation of a hyperplane is given as

$$f(x) = w^tx + b $$

Given $f(x) = 0$

show that the projection of a point x<sub>a</sub> on the plane is :

$$x_p = x_a - \frac{|f(x_a)|w}{\| w\|^2}$$

I was thinking of taking a unit vector lying on the plane and taking the dot product. But I am not getting the result I am looking for

Could anyone point me into the right direction ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do I interpret you correctly?  You're finding a unit vector $u$ in the plane, and taking the dot product in order to find the vector $w$?  This won't work since the set of vectors perpendicular to $u$ is another hyperplane.  What is the context of the problem?

Comment: @Doc Its a classification problem. f(x) is the decision boundary.

Comment: Choose $w$ s.t. $b\le0$. Then $x_p=x_a-\frac{f(x_a)}{\|w\|^2}w$.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense to me b is just an offset. Can you tell me why b should not be positive?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Do you want to show the formula you give for the projection is correct or what?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question . I have to prove the above formula

Answer (score 0):

For any two points $x$, $y$ on the hyperplane $\pi:\> f(x)=0$ one has $w\cdot(x-y)=f(x)-f(y)=0$. It follows that the vector $w$ (assumed $\ne0$) is orthogonal to $\pi$ and in fact defines the unique direction orthogonal to $\pi$. Therefore the line
$$g:\quad t\mapsto x_a+ t\>w\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)$$
is the projection ray we are interested in, and it only remains to intersect $g$ with $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks :) It seems I am getting the point projection at the intersection of the line and the plane.
But I don't understand how you chose this line and why is it orthogonal to the plane  
Could you please ellaborate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x_0\in f^{-1}(0)$. The projection of the vector $x_a-x_0$ onto $\text{span}\{w\}$ is the vector $\vec{n}=\frac{w^t(x_a-x_0)w}{\|w\|^2}$. If $x_p-x_0$ is the projection of the displacement vector $x_a-x_0$ onto $f^{-1}(0)$ then we have $$\begin{eqnarray*}(x_p-x_0)+\vec{n} & = & x_a-x_0\end{eqnarray*}$$ which means $$\begin{eqnarray*}x_p&=&x_a-\frac{w^t(x_a-x_0)w}{\|w\|^2} \\ &=& x_a -\Big(\frac{w^tx_a-w^tx_0}{\|w\|^2}\Big)w\end{eqnarray*}$$ Since $x_0\in f^{-1}(0)$ we have $w^tx_0+b=0$ so we can write this expression for $x_p$ as $$\begin{eqnarray*} x_p&=&x_a -\Big(\frac{w^tx_a+b}{\|w\|^2}\Big)w \\ &=& x_a -\frac{f(x_a)w}{\|w\|^2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider.

$w$ is the vector normal to the plane defined by $f(x) = 0$

For some point in space $x_a, f(x_a)$ returns an analog of distance of that point from the plane.  What is the actual distance? $\frac {|f(x_a)|}{\|w\|}$

We must then travel in the direction of the normal vector, toward the plane, the distance indicated above.

The unit normal in the direction of travel is $\text{sgn} (f(x_a)) \frac {w}{\|w\|}$